# Nested Loop method, RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

```
<div class="row">
  <% @group.each do |j| %>
    <% @group.each_with_index do |i, index| %>
      <% if j.category_id == i.category_id   %>
        <%= j.category_id%>
        <%= j.title %>
      <% break %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This is the result:
1 Ultimo de ultimo 1 Benza Comedia 1 Lazo Comedia 1 Juans comedia 1 Primer Titulo Comedia
2 acc last 2 Acc Benza 2 Juans Acc 2 Primer titulo Accion
3 terr last 3 Juans terr 3 Terror tittle
4 Juans rom 4 Romance tittle

I only want the result to be the first find.
I want it to only be: 1 Ultimo de ultimo, 2 acc last, 3 terr last and 4 Juans rom.

Answer (score 1):

You can try grouping it first

```
<div class="row">
  <% @group.group_by { |g| g.category_id }.each_with_index do |(key, val), index| %>
       <%= key %>
       <%= val.first.title %>
  <% end %>
 
</div>
```